# Difference in data sent/received with HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: http, ssl, https, tls1.2

I am curious to know the difference between the data sent over a HTTP connection and over HTTPS connection. I mean, what is the content, how it looks like in both cases. I am able for find for HTTP, but what is the corresponding content if same information is shared over HTTPS? HTTP contains `Request Line`, `Header` and `Message body`. I hope difference will be wrt `Message body`. Can anyone explain? Certificate content is embedded in this `Message body` or how is it?

Comment: HTTPS is just like HTTP, but the headers and the payload are encrypted.

Comment: and what about certificate? When I am sending a query to amazon, my browser is verifying identity of it. Is amazon's certificate part of payload?

Comment: The certificate is sent by the server when the connection is established and such certificate must be trusted by either the client itself or a party that the client trusts.

Comment: yes, how is that send, that is what I would like to know?

Comment: The certificate exchange is part of the transport layer. This [article](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html) may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would you like to mention all this below? Will accept your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150815/discussion-between-gauranga-and-cassio-mazzochi-molin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am curious to know the difference between the data sent over a HTTP connection and over HTTPS connection.

There is no difference.

> I mean, what is the content, how it looks like in both cases.

It is the same in both cases.

> I am able for find for HTTP, but what is the corresponding content if same information is shared over HTTPS?

It is the same.

> HTTP contains Request Line, Header and Message body.

And so does HTTPS.

> I hope difference will be wrt Message body.

The difference is in the fac that the entire payload is encrypted.

> Can anyone explain?

I have endeavoured to do so.

> Certificate content is embedded in this Message body

No.

> or how is it?

It is embedded in the TLS handshake, which precedes any data exchange over the connection, including the entirety of any HTTP content.

Answer (score 3):

In HTTPS (HTTP over SSL) the HTTP request is performed over a SSL tunel, hence both the HTTP headers and the payload are encrypted.

The certificate is sent by the server when the connection is established, as part of the TLS handshake. Such certificate must be trusted by either the client itself or a party that the client trusts.

---

<sup>Probably this [article](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html) will give you a better understanding of the handshake.</sup>